# Change combo-box style and color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `combobox` and I want to change its style and color. Should become white instead of gray. How should I do that?

I tried with `OpacityMask = "White"`, which did not work for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following Example

```
  <Style TargetType="ComboBox">

            <Setter Property="ComboBox.BorderBrush"
                    Value="LightSlateGray" />
            <Setter Property="ComboBox.Background"
                    Value="white" />
            <Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

For WPF:

```
var combo = new Combobox(); 
combo.Background = Brushes.White;
combo.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
```

Or you want to check Style Triggers:

```
<!-- Corrected XAML syntax. -->
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: `BackColor` property doens't exist for WPF comboBox.

Comment: I thought Winform , i modified the answer

Comment: Question is tagged `WPF` and moreover all posted answers along with this one doesn't works. Have you tried it?

Comment: Doesn't work in Window 8 atleast. Could not test on other OS though.

Answer (score 1):

This style will be aplied to all your combo-boxes.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="White" /> 
</Style>
```

If you want in a specific combobox use:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" /> 
</Style>
```

For a complete template check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use `BackgroundColor` property for setting the color of that control.

Comment: `BackgroundColor` property doesn't exist for WPF combobox.