# Change color of combobox(title box of combo box in which arrow button is displayed)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to change the color permanently of the box(title box of combo box in which arrow button is displayed) in combobox in which title of the combobox is displayed,how to do this tried lot many things but it is not that what i want

Comment: You need to change combobox template and in that need to change Toggle button background to change arrow button background.Visit in the "Designer" view of visual studio right click on the combobox-> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            **<Border x:Name="Border" Style="{DynamicResource LightGrayBox}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{StaticResource BlueColor}" />**
                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0.6" Fill="{StaticResource GrayColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BlueColor}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlueColor}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BlueColor}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Include the line in BOLD in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple. You just have to add resources and consume resources.

try this :

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="stylecombo" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ComboBox.Background"
                    Value="Beige" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource stylecombo}" Height="25" Width="100" Margin="23,22,285,262" IsEditable="True" Text="Your Choice...">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="1"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="2"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

If you are using usercontrol, use UserControl.Resources instead of Window.Resources.

Hope this will help you.!! :)

Comment: Can you please show me your code which you have tried. As I tried creating WPF application and this code worked fine.

Comment: With that code my solution supposed to work. I am saying this as I have created demo application to test it. I think you have catch somewhere else in your program.

Comment: Isn't your question identical with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454167/change-combo-box-style-and-color?rq=1  ???

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of either Retemplating the combobox control, or Get the TemplatedChild elements of the control..

The first one is the one i use myself the most, so that I have something consistent throughout my application.

ComboBox ResourceDictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Shared.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!-- SimpleStyles: ComboBox -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    x:Name="Border" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    CornerRadius="2"
    Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxButtonBackgroundBrush}"
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
    BorderThickness="1" />
        <!--Border for colonne 1 i ComboBoxen-->
        <Border 
    Grid.Column="0"
    CornerRadius="0" 
    Margin="1" 
    Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxBackgroundBrush}" 
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
    BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
        <Path 
    x:Name="Arrow"
    Grid.Column="1"     
    Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Data="M -2 -1 L 6 2 L -2 6"/> 
    </Grid>
    <!-- 
        Consider path data as a grid with cordinates.
        It makes the drawing logic so much easier.
         M = starts at (x, y)
         L = Line, drawing line from last point (x, y)
         H = Horizontal line from last point to new point (x)
         V = Vertical line from last point to new point (y)
         C = Curves (x¹, y¹, x², y², x, y) advanced math
         S = Curves (x², y², x, y) advanced math
         Q = Curves (x¹, y¹, x, y) advanced math
         T = Curves (x,y) advanced math
    -->
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>

          <ToggleButton 
          Name="ToggleButton" 
          Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
          Grid.Column="2" 
          Focusable="false"
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
          ClickMode="Press">
          </ToggleButton>

          <ContentPresenter
          Name="ContentSite"
          IsHitTestVisible="False" 
          Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
          Margin="3,3,23,3"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          />

          <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
          Style="{x:Null}" 
          Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Margin="3,3,23,3"
          Focusable="True" 
          Background="Transparent"
          Visibility="Hidden"
          IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
          />

          <Popup 
          Name="Popup"
          Placement="Bottom"
          IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
          AllowsTransparency="True" 
          Focusable="False"
          PopupAnimation="Slide"
          >
```

```
            <Grid 
            Name="DropDown"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
            MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
            MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
            >

              <Border 
              x:Name="DropDownBorder"
              Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
              BorderThickness="1"
              BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />

                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/> 
                        <!-- Her sættes der margin og corner radius på dropdownlisten. -->
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!-- SimpleStyles: ComboBoxItem -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Border 
        Name="Border"
        Padding="2"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is the example of the original template with some minor changes. Here you can change whatever you like in the control since all the templated children is there aswell.

Comment: Sorry about the window split in my answer, I can't seem to fix it. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Window.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="GrayColor_">#FF928B81</Color>
        <Color x:Key="LightGrayColor_">#FFC3C3C3</Color>
        <Color x:Key="LightLightGrayColor_">#FFF1F1F1</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayColor" Color="{StaticResource GrayColor_}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGrayColor" Color="{StaticResource LightGrayColor_}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightLightGrayColor" Color="{StaticResource LightLightGrayColor_}"/>

        <Color x:Key="BlueColor_">#0073b0</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DarkBlueColor_">#FF004165</Color>
        <Color x:Key="LightBlueColor_">#FFa4ddfa</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueColor" Color="{StaticResource BlueColor_}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkBlueColor" Color="{StaticResource DarkBlueColor_}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBlueColor" Color="{StaticResource LightBlueColor_}" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Foreground" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundWhite" Color="White"/>


        <Style x:Key="LightGrayBox" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LightGrayColor}" />
        </Style>


        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Style="{DynamicResource LightGrayBox}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0.6" Fill="{StaticResource GrayColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BlueColor}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlueColor}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BlueColor}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButtonActive" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{DynamicResource BlueColor}" />
                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="1" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlueColor}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="StandardComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Grid.Column="2" Focusable="false" ClickMode="Press"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                            <Label Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                               ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <!--<ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" 
                                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />-->
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" 
                                 CaretBrush="{DynamicResource ForegroundWhite}"
                                 Style="{x:Null}" 
                                 Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                 Margin="3,3,23,3" 
                                 Focusable="True" 
                                 Background="Transparent" 
                                 Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundWhite}" 
                                 Visibility="Hidden"
                                 IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                            <Popup VerticalOffset="-1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True"  Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                                <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="200">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Style="{DynamicResource LightGrayBox}"/>
                                    <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="ToggleButton" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonActive}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundWhite}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Foreground}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Foreground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlueColor}"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Padding" Value="2,3,2,3" />
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>

                </Style>

            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Height="23" Margin="122,32,100,0" Style="{StaticResource StandardComboBox}"  Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top">

        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: It is changing the background color of combo box item,and i want to change the color of box in which "Your Choice.." is displayed- my code is- <ComboBox Margin="137,128,171,156" IsEditable="True" Text="Your Choice..."> <ComboBoxItem Content="1"></ComboBoxItem> <ComboBoxItem Content="2"></ComboBoxItem> </ComboBox>

Comment: Thanks,but one more thing is required,when i click on combobox then changed color appears everywhere,but i dont want it be on onclick,i want that changed color should appear always,that is when window is loaded,combo box with changed color should come

Answer (score 0):

The template of combo box says that its background is transparent, just add a panel/grid behind it and change the color of panel/grid to desired color, it will change to that color.

You will have to create a grid, set its background color, bring it over the combo box control, set its height and width to match with combo box, and right click the combo box, go to order, select bring to front.

This will do the trick.
Works with me :)